# Are the people of Earth truly united?

Tags: futurama

In Futurama, the country in which the story it sets is generally called "Earth"; and people are referred to as "Earthican".

Still, the UN still exists (which seems contrary to the idea of a unified Earthican nation); and the "Earthican" flag is clearly a US flag, with an image of the Americas replacing the stars.

It's also shown explicitly that various offices of state exist, such as the Prime Minister of Norway, which makes little sense in the context of a united Earth.

Is the question ever explicitly addressed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_in_Futurama) says that there is a unified Earth government, but that individual countries still have their own government. I'd say that this sounds a lot like a Republic, with the local governments each sending their representatives to the UN to deal in Earth-wide manners.

This makes sense given the inherent inefficiency of trying to run *everything* from a central government. Clearly, local issues are handled on a local level, with big-picture issues (civil rights, war & interstellar relations) handled at the UN level.